# Fresh sbt installation fails: duplicate label 'local' in section 'repositories'

Tags: sbt

I installed sbt using

```
brew install sbt
```

but when I try to start `sbt` shell or any other command like

```
sbt
```

or

```
sbt sbtVersion
```

it shows error

```
[error] [launcher] error during sbt launcher: duplicate label 'local' in section 'repositories'
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Which OS are you on? Do you have a file `~/.sbt/repositories`, if yes, check if it has `local` mentioned twice.

Comment: Thank you this works, I guess I made a mistake while creating that file.